# Visualizing time-series interactively in Ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, bokeh, holoviews

I have a 2D matrix where the rows are different (Long, Lat) values and columns are different dates. The entry in the matrix can contain nan values specifying that data for that date is not available. I want to plot (Long, Lat) values on a world Map such that each point is represented by a small circle in the map and whenever I click on that point time series for that point (using dates attribute) should get plotted. I want to see and plot interactively a lot of time series and hence would like to know how to do it interactively.

Comment: It is easy to implement this with holoviews or bokeh, can you use these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of the following could be relevant (tap a heatmap, get a timeseries)
http://holoviews.org/reference/streams/bokeh/Tap.html and this one (draw 
 a box, get a timeseries) http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/box_draw_roi_editor.html#bokeh-gallery-box-draw-roi-editor